# Chrome: Can not connect to a running headless instance via debugging port

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to connect to "Headless chrome" from with a normal Chrome app (with GUI).
I have started the headless process like below:
`chromedriver --headless --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0  --allowed-ips=127.0.0.1 --allowed-origins=* --port=9533`

And in my GUI Chrome, I go to chrome://inspect/#devices and in the "Discover network targets" I enter "127.0.0.1:9533" and as a result, I can see a new entry "Remote Target" in the list. But there is nothing else there. No inspect, no list of open tabs, ... .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Turns out "chromedriver" is just a "proxy" on top of actual chrome (to provide a WebDriver compatible interface for Selenium) and I can't connect to it via above method. What I can connect to, is an actual "Chrome" process (which is run as headless) and this worked fine.